# Structures definition problem in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have a few structures with cross-pointers in my program, they are defined like this:

```
typedef struct
{
 ...
 struct myvar *next;
 struct myvar *prev;
 ...
} myvar;

typedef struct
{
 ...
 myvar *first;
 ...
} variables;
```

And I am getting a strange error on the next piece of code:

```
variables *Variables;
...
Variables->first->prev->next = Variables->first;
```

I am using MS Visual Studio, and it says

```
error C2037: left of 'next' specifies undefined struct/union 'myvar'
```

I have set it to Compile as C Code (/TC), in C++ mode all is ok. What is the problem and is there some workaround except something like this?

```
tmp = Variables->first->prev;
tmp->next = Variables->first;
```

Comment: It's better to show which line makes the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I constantly run into these problems, too :) Forward-declaring your typedefs should help you in your situation:

```
typedef struct _myvar myvar;
typedef struct _variables variables;

struct _myvar
{
    ...
    myvar *next;
    myvar *prev;
    ...
};

struct _variables
{
    ...
    myvar *first;
    ...
};
```

Comment: "_" beginning names are reserved for compiler internal use, you should not use this

Answer (score 4):

Here is your problem:

```
typedef struct
{
 ...
 struct myvar *next;
 struct myvar *prev;
 ...
} myvar;
```

You should change it to this

```
typedef struct myvar_
{
 ...
 struct myvar_ *next;
 struct myvar_ *prev;
 ...
} myvar;
```

The problem is that in the first version, you're telling the compiler there is going to be a definition of struct `myvar`. But you never define a struct named `myvar`. You just have an anonymous struct and `typedef` is as `myvar`, which doesn't count. So `next` and `prev` remain of incomplete type.

Comment: +1: The very subtle issue is that you can use a `struct myvar` to point to an unknown structure type with tag `myvar`, which is some structure other than the structure that is given the typdef name `myvar`.  The trailing underscore is not necessary; I'd simply use `typedef struct myvar { ... } myvar;` because tag names and typedef names are distinct namespaces.